# Isolated singularity: why is $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ pole?

Tags: complex-analysis

Why is $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ pole? Singularity is in $z=i$ but how do I show that $\lim_{z \to i} |f(z)|=\infty $?

Comment: There are poles at $z=\pm i$. But at $z=0$ $f$ is analytic. So $\lim_{z \to 0}|f(z)| = |f(0)| =1$.

Comment: That's probably a typo, I assume she meant $\lim_{z \to i}$...

Comment: Yes I edited it.

Comment: English... Do not say: $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ is pole.  Instead say: $i$ is a pole of  $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ ... or $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ has a pole at $z=i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have a singularity at $z = -i$.

Just write
$$\frac{1}{z^2+1} = \frac{i}{2}\left( \frac{1}{z-i}-\frac{1}{z+i} \right)$$

Near $z = i$, the second term is bounded and you have $\vert z-i \vert \to 0$ when $z \to i$ so
$$ \left\vert \frac{1}{z-i} \right\vert = \frac{1}{\vert z-i \vert} \longrightarrow + \infty$$
when $z \to i$.